# python script to read and write a path to registry

Tags: python-2.7, winreg

I have developed a python script where i have a setting window which has the options to select the paths for the installation of software.When clicked on OK button of the setting window, i want to write all the selected paths to the registry and read the same when setting window is opened again.
My code looks as below.

```
def OnOk(self, event):
    data1=self.field1.GetValue() #path selected in setting window
    aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    keyVal=OpenKey(aReg,r"SOFTWARE\my path to\Registry", 0,KEY_WRITE)
    try:
       SetValueEx(keyVal,"Log file",0,REG_SZ,data1)
    except EnvironmentError:
       pass
    CloseKey(keyVal)
    CloseKey(aReg)
```

I get a error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\PROJECT\project.py", line 305, in OnOk
keyVal=OpenKey(aReg,r"SOFTWARE\my path to\Registry", 0,KEY_WRITE)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

And to read from registry,the saved registry has to show up in the setting window.I tried with the below code.Though its working but not satisfied with the way i programmed it.Help me out for the better solution

```
key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\my path to\Registry', 0, KEY_READ)
    for i in range(4): 
        try:
            n,v,t = EnumValue(key,i)
            if i==0:
                self.field2.SetValue(v)
            elif i==1:
                self.field3.SetValue(v)
            elif i==2:
                self.field4.SetValue(v)
            elif i==3:
                self.field1.SetValue(v)
        except EnvironmentError:                                               
            pass
CloseKey(key)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python script to read from registry is as follows:

```
try:
    root_key=OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'SOFTWARE\my path to\Registry', 0, KEY_READ)
    [Pathname,regtype]=(QueryValueEx(root_key,"Pathname"))
    CloseKey(root_key)
    if (""==Pathname):
        raise WindowsError
except WindowsError:
    return [""]
```

Python script to write to the registry is:

```
try:
    keyval=r"SOFTWARE\my path to\Registry"
    if not os.path.exists("keyval"):
        key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,keyval)
    Registrykey= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"SOFTWARE\my path to\Registry", 0,KEY_WRITE)
    SetValueEx(Registrykey,"Pathname",0,REG_SZ,Pathname)
    CloseKey(Registrykey)
    return True
except WindowsError:
    return False
```

Hope it helps you all.Cheers:)

Comment: That part about `if not os.path.exists("keyval")` looks very wrong to me. On windows, it's looking for a file at `"C:\Users\YOURNAME\keyval"` to see if it exists, and it probably doesn't, so it calls `CreateKey()` every time. I don't see how that would ever work, even if you took the quotes off of it.

Comment: Also, `CreateKey()` just opens the key if it already exists. I would probably try to catch the `OSError` raised by `OpenKey()` if I was worried about the key not existing, and just use `CreateKey()` if I want to ensure it exists.

Answer (score 39):

```
#Python3 version of hugo24's snippet
import winreg

REG_PATH = r"Control Panel\Mouse"

def set_reg(name, value):
    try:
        winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH)
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, 
                                       winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

def get_reg(name):
    try:
        registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0,
                                       winreg.KEY_READ)
        value, regtype = winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
        winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return value
    except WindowsError:
        return None

#Example MouseSensitivity
#Read value 
print (get_reg('MouseSensitivity'))

#Set Value 1/20 (will just write the value to reg, the changed mouse val requires a win re-log to apply*)
set_reg('MouseSensitivity', str(10))

#*For instant apply of SystemParameters like the mouse speed on-write, you can use win32gui/SPI
#http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32gui__SystemParametersInfo_meth.html
```

Comment: So basically it's enough to remove the underscore from `_winreg` :)

Comment: There is a bug in this code. If there is an exception, CloseKey() will never get called. It is better to use `with winreg.OpenKey(...) as registry_key:` block, which will ensure that the key is closed when the block is exited, even when there is an exception.

Answer (score 17):

Same as @Aramanethota but with pep8 and func def for easy usage.

```
REG_PATH = r"SOFTWARE\my_program\Settings"

def set_reg(name, value):
    try:
        _winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH)
        registry_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0, 
                                       _winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        _winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        _winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False

def get_reg(name):
    try:
        registry_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REG_PATH, 0,
                                       _winreg.KEY_READ)
        value, regtype = _winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
        _winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
        return value
    except WindowsError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 5):

Reading registry keys:

```
def read(path, root=HKEY_CURRENT_USER):
    path, name = os.path.split(path)
    with suppress(FileNotFoundError), OpenKey(root, path) as key:
        return QueryValueEx(key, name)[0]
```

And writing:

```
def write(path, value, root=HKEY_CURRENT_USER):
    path, name = os.path.split(path)
    with OpenKey(root, path, 0, KEY_WRITE) as key:
        SetValueEx(key, name, 0, REG_SZ, value)
```

Extended for type handling. Provide type as argument, match current type in registry or python value type.

```
def write(path, value, root=HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regtype=None):
    path, name = os.path.split(path)
    with OpenKey(root, path, 0, KEY_WRITE|KEY_READ) as key:
        with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
            regtype = regtype or QueryValueEx(key, name)[1]

        SetValueEx(key, name, 0, regtype or REG_DWORD if isinstance(value, int) else REG_SZ, str(value) if regtype==REG_SZ else value)
```

> **NOTE:** Use of [contextlib.suppress()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) (available since `python 3.4`) can be replaced by try..except..pass for older versions. The [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.PyHKEY.__enter__) interface for winreg was introduced in `python 2.6`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have permission to edit the Registry. Incase if you are Admin, Please run this script in Elevated state.

Comment: Yes i was using the guest user,so i did not get it right. I changed the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER and it's working fine now.

Comment: IS HKEY_CURRENT_USER works for both admin and other user account??

Comment: If Guest user can Access the key in registry, then so can Admin.

Comment: Thank u @Travis G. I will go with HKEY_CURRENT USER.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I wrote (python 2) which has the ability to restore state when you finish manipulating the registry. The class was not tested properly so it may contain some bugs:

```
import _winreg as winreg

class Registry(object):
    def __init__(self, restore_state=False):
        self.m_backup = {}
        self.m_restore_state = restore_state

    def get_key(self, hkey, subkey, access, create_if_doesnt_exist=True):
        created_key = False
        registry_key = None
        try:
            registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(hkey, subkey, 0, access)
        except WindowsError:
            try:
                if create_if_doesnt_exist:
                    registry_key = winreg.CreateKey(hkey, subkey)
                    if registry_key not in self.m_backup:
                        self.m_backup[registry_key] = ({}, (hkey, subkey))
                else:
                    registry_key = None
            except WindowsError:
                if registry_key:
                    self.close_key(registry_key)
                raise Exception('Registry does not exist and could not be created.')
        return registry_key   

    def close_key(self, registry_key):
        closed = False
        if registry_key:
            try:
                winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
                closed = True
            except:
                closed = False
        return closed          

    def get_reg_value(self, hkey, subkey, name):
        value = None
        registry_key = self.get_key(hkey, subkey, winreg.KEY_READ, False)
        if registry_key:
            try:
                value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(registry_key, name)
            except WindowsError:
                value = None
            finally:
                self.close_key(registry_key)
        return value

    def set_reg_value(self, hkey, subkey, name, type, value):
        registry_key = self.get_key(hkey, subkey, winreg.KEY_WRITE, True)
        backed_up = False
        was_set = False
        if registry_key:
            if self.m_restore_state:
                if registry_key not in self.m_backup:
                    self.m_backup[registry_key] = ({}, None)
                existing_value = self.get_reg_value(hkey, subkey, name)
                if existing_value:
                    self.m_backup[registry_key][0][name] = (existing_value, type, False)
                else:
                    self.m_backup[registry_key][0][name] = (None, None, True)
                backed_up = True                
            try:
                winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, type, value)
                was_set = True
            except WindowsError:
                was_set = False
            finally:
                if not backed_up:
                    self.close_key(registry_key)
        return was_set

    def restore_state(self):
        if self.m_restore_state:
            for registry_key, data in self.m_backup.iteritems():
                backup_dict, key_info = data
                try:
                    for name, backup_data in backup_dict.iteritems():
                        value, type, was_created = backup_data
                        if was_created:
                            print registry_key, name
                            winreg.DeleteValue(registry_key, name)
                        else:
                            winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, type, value)
                    if key_info:
                        hkey, subkey = key_info
                        winreg.DeleteKey(hkey, subkey)
                except:
                    raise Exception('Could not restore value')
                self.close_key(registry_key)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.m_restore_state:
            self.restore_state()
```

Answer (score 1):

for Creating / writing values in registry key:

```
from winreg import*
import winreg

keyVal = r'SOFTWARE\\python'


try:
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyVal, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
except:
    key = CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyVal)
SetValueEx(key, "Start Page", 0, REG_SZ, "snakes")
CloseKey(key)
```

If access denied - try running the command (CMd or IDE) in administrative mode

for reading value in registry-key

```
from winreg import*
Registry = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
RawKey = OpenKey(Registry, "SOFTWARE\\python")
try:
    i = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = EnumValue(RawKey, i)
        print("name:",name,"value:", value,"i:", i)
        i += 1
except WindowsError:
    print("")
```

Comment: In the write example the statement "import winreg" is pointless. The variable "keyval" is better named "keypath". The key's valuename and the actual value are better defined by variables such as [valuename = "Start Page"] and [regszvalue = "snakes"].

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def add_key(name,pathh):
    try:
        keyval=r"System\my path\Register"
        if not os.path.exists("keyval"):
            key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,keyval)
        Registrykey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"System\my path\Register", 0,winreg.KEY_WRITE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(Registrykey,name,1,winreg.REG_SZ,pathh)
        winreg.CloseKey(Registrykey)
        return True
    except WindowsError:
        return False
```

Comment: There are 7 other answers to this question, one of them "accepted" (7 years ago).  I cannot tell if this adds value -- perhaps if it was better formatted it might (just) ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'winreg' module is so ...strange working module, so, I wrote a class called 'WindowsRegistry' for working with Windows registry and 'winreg' module easier. I hope it will be more usefull:

```
import winreg
import re


class WindowsRegistry:
    """Class WindowsRegistry is using for easy manipulating Windows registry.


    Methods
    -------
    query_value(full_path : str)
        Check value for existing.

    get_value(full_path : str)
        Get value's data.

    set_value(full_path : str, value : str, value_type='REG_SZ' : str)
        Create a new value with data or set data to an existing value.

    delete_value(full_path : str)
        Delete an existing value.

    query_key(full_path : str)
        Check key for existing.

    delete_key(full_path : str)
        Delete an existing key(only without subkeys).


    Examples:
        WindowsRegistry.set_value('HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run', 'Program', r'"c:\Dir1\program.exe"')
        WindowsRegistry.delete_value('HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run/Program')
    """
    @staticmethod
    def __parse_data(full_path):
        full_path = re.sub(r'/', r'\\', full_path)
        hive = re.sub(r'\\.*$', '', full_path)
        if not hive:
            raise ValueError('Invalid \'full_path\' param.')
        if len(hive) <= 4:
            if hive == 'HKLM':
                hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
            elif hive == 'HKCU':
                hive = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER'
            elif hive == 'HKCR':
                hive = 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT'
            elif hive == 'HKU':
                hive = 'HKEY_USERS'
        reg_key = re.sub(r'^[A-Z_]*\\', '', full_path)
        reg_key = re.sub(r'\\[^\\]+$', '', reg_key)
        reg_value = re.sub(r'^.*\\', '', full_path)

        return hive, reg_key, reg_value

    @staticmethod
    def query_value(full_path):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            opened_key = winreg.OpenKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1], 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
            winreg.QueryValueEx(opened_key, value_list[2])
            winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
            return True
        except WindowsError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def get_value(full_path):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            opened_key = winreg.OpenKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1], 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
            value_of_value, value_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(opened_key, value_list[2])
            winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
            return value_of_value
        except WindowsError:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def set_value(full_path, value, value_type='REG_SZ'):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            winreg.CreateKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1])
            opened_key = winreg.OpenKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1], 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)
            winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, value_list[2], 0, getattr(winreg, value_type), value)
            winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
            return True
        except WindowsError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def delete_value(full_path):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            opened_key = winreg.OpenKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1], 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)
            winreg.DeleteValue(opened_key, value_list[2])
            winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
            return True
        except WindowsError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def query_key(full_path):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            opened_key = winreg.OpenKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1] + r'\\' + value_list[2], 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
            winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
            return True
        except WindowsError:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def delete_key(full_path):
        value_list = WindowsRegistry.__parse_data(full_path)
        try:
            winreg.DeleteKey(getattr(winreg, value_list[0]), value_list[1] + r'\\' + value_list[2])
            return True
        except WindowsError:
            return False
```

Comment: tested? Your set_value variables and examples seem to be in conflict

Comment: It was 2 years ago, I remember I used it, but for now I was complitely forgotten python:D