# How to use DesiredCapabilities class through IEDriverServer in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have been struggling with a simple python script working in IE11 for some reason it was unable to find any elemnt, however by setting some desired capabilities in a java code it worked:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Python27\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);//
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
WebElement search =driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
search.sendKeys("selenium");
search.submit();
```

However, since I already wrote my tests in python I would like to use the same method in python:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['executablePath'] = 'C:\\Python27\\IEDriverServer.exe'
caps['InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps)
browser.get('https://google.com')
search = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
search.send_keys("selenium")
search.submit()
```

But for some reason, selenium is still unable to find the search bar, so I'm guessing the equivalent I wrote in python isn't right, can someone point me out to the right direction please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python protection settings IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677127/python-protection-settings-ie)

Answer (score 3):

You have to take care of a couple of facts as follows:

- Instead of using `DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER` you need to use `DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()`.

> **Note**: Always append `.copy()` on the *DesiredCapabilities* object to avoid the side effects of altering the Global class instance.

- As per the [The Desired Capabilities implementation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities) `executablePath()` is not any valid argument. Instead pass the argument `executable_path` when initializing the *WebDriver*/*WebClient*.
- As you have added the option `introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains()`, as per the discussion in the blog [You're Doing It Wrong: IE Protected Mode and WebDriver](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) @JimEvans clearly mentioned that adding `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` may get you past the initial exception and will allow the test to run in most cases without incident. However using this capability doesn't solve the underlying problem though. If a *Protected Mode Boundary* is crossed, very unexpected behavior including *hangs*, *element location not working*, and *clicks not being propagated*, could occur.
- As you are sending a *character sequence* to the *Google Search Box* instead of `presence_of_element_located()` method use **`element_to_be_clickable()`** method.
- Here is your own code with a couple of modifications:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  cap = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
  cap['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
  driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe')
  driver.get('https://google.com')
  search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'q')))
  search.send_keys("selenium")
  search.submit()
  ```

---

### Browser Snapshot

[image: google_search_selenium_ie]

---

### Reference

Here you find a detailed discussion on [**Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 with Selenium 3.13.0: IEDriverServer_x64_3.13.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165929/unexpected-error-launching-internet-explorer-ielaunchurl-returned-hresult-800/51169697#51169697)