# Is it possible to create shortcuts into a specific directory in python?

Tags: python, directory, shortcut

I looked over the inetrnet but found nothing about this so I ask here - 
Is it possible to create a shortcut of a file and put it in a specific directory of my choose with python? 
For example, I have a folder named "EXAMPLE" in ' C: ' . I want to create automatically a shortcut of Google Chrome and put it in this folder. Is it possible to do so using python(and not just dragging it over by myself)?
Thanks

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I assume because of you mention C: that you're using windows. So you can use winshell

```
import os, winshell
from win32com.client import Dispatch

desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join(desktop, "Media Player Classic.lnk")
target = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"
wDir = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic"
icon = r"P:\Media\Media Player Classic\mplayerc.exe"

shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

For more info look at [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/23/using-python-to-create-shortcuts/)

If you're on a unix-based system you can use the symbolic link command.

Comment: Thanks! In addition, is it possible to check if the shortcut is already exsits before creating a new one? So that there will be only 1 shortcut and not more than 1 for the same file..?

Comment: It's just a file so you can do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python

Comment: Thank you very much!

I had an issue where I was doing var = r"link\\to\\path" where I was adding two \\ instead of 1.

So if you want the folder shortcut to work, make sure your path is set to path = r"path\to\folder" where you only have 1 \ , not \\.

Hope it helps anyone who gets stuck in this like I did.