# How to make an installer the way it creates an icon on desktop?

Tags: python, installation, nsis, pynsist, fbs

I've got ready, already compiled python application for windows but there is a problem with making an installer, which creates desktop icon for it when you check a corresponding mark.

I made an installer using clean `NSIS` script, `fbs` and `pynsist`. Actually, there is no problem to create an installer which downloads your app to `Program Files` but however I haven't found the way to create an icon which will be shown on desktop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create shortcuts into a specific directory in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154767/is-it-possible-to-create-shortcuts-into-a-specific-directory-in-python)

Comment: What does your installer.cfg look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pynsist does not seem to have a way to inject extra code for some reason but you can override the entire install script.

Make a copy of your pyapp.nsi file (or [grab it from Github](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/blob/master/nsist/pyapp.nsi)).

There are two places in the file where it does `CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\....`. 
Add another line under it with:

```
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\[[scname]].lnk" "[[sc['target'] ]]" '[[ sc['parameters'] ]]' "$INSTDIR\[[ sc['icon'] ]]"
```

And finally, in your installer.cfg file, add/set

```
[Build]
nsi_template=c:\my_custom_pyapp.nsi
```

Comment: The nsi template file is actually a way to inject extra code, though the details aren't really documented. It uses Jinja templating, which allows for inheriting from a parent template and extending blocks defined there. E.g. you could extend the `install_shortcuts` block. `[[ super() ]]` inserts the contents of the block from the parent template.

Comment: @ThomasK Feel free to edit my answer or add your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, running my `installer.cfg` gives me jinja's `TemplateNotFoundError`. I've done everything you asked me to do. Should my installer work anyway or is there something I should edit?

Comment: @TimKoval Well, you need to change "c:\my_custom_pyapp.nsi" to where you saved the .nsi.

Comment: @ThomasK thanks for the hint, took me a while how to get it to work, here it is for future generations https://gist.github.com/janmechtel/16d0536e81fd5da93acd731341abc5a5